# How do I add a counter to show how many times a div element has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a basic website for a personal project. I have a div element in the code as well. When a user clicks this particular div element, I want the site to display a counter next to the div element to count how many times it has been clicked. I don't need to save anywhere else how many times it has been clicked. Is this possible with JS and how could I do this?

I don't know much Javascript at all, so I haven't known what exactly to try.

I want to have a basic counter next to the element to count how many times it has been counted. Again, nothing needs to be saved a server. Also, I am not worried about how many times a user can click the div element and add another number.

Answer (score 2):

First you need a counter where you store the number of clicks

```
let clicks = 0;
```

Then you need to find your div in the DOM using

```
document.getElementById() // or
document.getElemenyByClass() // or similar
```

An example of finding your div would be

```
my_div = document.getElementById("click_div");
```

Then you need to add an [Event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the div

Something like this

```
my_div.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // add code here that increases the /clicks/ variable
});
```

Comment: Thank you for giving detailed comments about every step and leaving a small mystery for the OP to solve. That's how we all learned.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow @Gabrielle! I understand that your new to JavaScript and haven't been able to find a meaningful answer to attempt this project.

Lets start basic first, in JavaScript, we need to store the value of clicks, so we declare a variable

`i = 0`

Now we want to give that specific div an ID, so lets say `<div id="special"> Some Content...</div>`

Within our JavaScript code block, we need to reference to special, so we create another variable,

`myDiv = document.getElementById("special")`

`myDiv` now is referenced to that special div you want to track. Next we create the on click event to track clicks on that element.

`myDiv.addEventListener("click",function(){ Clicked! Do something... })`

`addEventListener` tells the DOM that it wants to listen to clicks occurring onto that element only and if so, trigger the instructions inside of the function tag.

Now we increase the counter, or the variable `i` each time a click occurs, so we use 
`i += 1`

This way each click that occurs, `i` adds one to itself.

Lastly we have to show that number to another special ID on the page, I will leave that part "Since its simple" to you to figure out but I will reference it below.

```js
// Variables
i = 0;
myDiv = document.getElementById("special");

// Event Listeners
myDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
  i += 1;
  console.log(i);
});
```

```html
<div id="special">Click Me!</div>
```

Some help with displaying the number inside of your page, go to [JS Inner HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Hope this helped! Don't forget to thumbs this up if it did!

Answer (score 1):

I’ve created a div and filled it with a colour to make it easily distinguishable. Clicking on the div will produce a pop-up where the count increments with each click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
    div {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>

<head> </head>

<body>
    <script>
        let count = 0;

        function counter() {
            count = count + 1;
            alert(count);
        }
    </script>

    <div onclick="counter()"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a basic counter like this? You can also add the eventlistener to a normal div (doesn't need to be a button element):

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      let counter = 0
      document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
        counter++
        document.querySelector(".counter").innerHTML = counter
      });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<button id="button">Click!</button>
<div class="counter">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to give your divs labels that javascript can target. We can use `id` because they are unique. For example:

```
<div id="clicker"></div>
```

The way javascript targets `id` is via `document.getElementById("clicker")`

Next, we need to know when the div is being clicked. We do this by attaching a "listener" to the div that tracks "clicks":

```
document.getElementById("clicker").addEventListener("click", ...
```

Now, when a click is detected, that the function (i.e. code) that is attached to the click will run. The following explains the code in the function.

We use `.textContent` to retrieve the text content in the div, and assign it to the variable `count`:

```
let count = document.getElementById("counter").textContent;
```

Since count is a string, we convert it to numbers first with the `parseInt` function. Not all the time necessary in javascript as it automatically coverts, but good practice anyhow.

```
parseInt(count);
```

Now that we know it's a number, we can add one to it. This is a short form:

```
counter++; // same as saying counter = counter + 1;
```

Remember how we got the text content from the div with `.textContent`? We can also set the text content with the same `.textContent` like so:

```
document.getElementById("counter").textContent = count; //set to new value
```

Putting it together:

```js
// target the "clicker" div and adds a listener to detect clicks
document.getElementById("clicker").addEventListener("click", function (event) { // for each click, it will run this function
    // get current value from "counter" div
    let count = document.getElementById("counter").textContent;
    // turn string to integer
    parseInt(count);
    // add one
    count++;
    // set the new value back to "counter" div
    document.getElementById("counter").textContent = count;
    
});
```

```css
div {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 5px;
   border: solid 1px gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="clicker">click here</div><div id="counter">0</div>
```

Comment: It would be much more appropriate to not give a full ready code, but to leave some room for understanding and self knowledge to the OP. Try to use as much simplicity when an OP says hes new to a specific language. Otherwise your code does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very beginner-friendly way to do it:

**HTML and CSS:**
The HTML contains two `div` elements (each with its own `id` attribute so our JavaScript code can easily find them.) And the CSS improves the appearance of the HTML.

**JavaScript:**
Two variables are created, and each one stores a reference to one of the `div` elements.
An event listener is created, to notice whenever a `click` event happens on the page and respond by calling the `count` function.

The `count` function is created. Most of its statements are wrapped inside an `if` block, so that the code will only execute if the condition is met. (The triggering condition is that the target of the `click` event was the div element whose `id` attribute has the value "`clickableDiv`".)

Now whenever a click happens, if the condition is met, the rest of the code runs:

1. Two variables are created: `oldCount` and `newCount`.
2. `oldCount` is assigned a value. (That value is the output of calling
   the built-in `parseInt()` function, using whatever is inside the
   `counterDiv` element as the input.
3. `newCount` is assigned a
   value. (That value is one more than the value in `oldCount`.)
4. Whatever is inside the `counterDiv` element is replaced with the
   value stored in `newCount`.

```js
// Defines references to elements (using `const` because the values
//   should never change)
const clickableDiv = document.getElementById("clickableDiv");
const counterDiv = document.getElementById("counterDiv");

// Defines a listener that will call our function whenever a click happens
document.addEventListener("click", count);

// Defines the `count` function
function count(event){

  // Limits which click events will change our counter
  if (event.target == clickableDiv){

    // Declares variables to hold numbers (using `let` in case we 
    //   might want to change the values later)
    let oldCount;
    let newCount;

    // Assumes the HTML content of counterDiv looks like a number, 
    // gets that number, and stores it in oldCount
    oldCount = parseInt(counterDiv.innerHTML);

    // Adds 1 to the number stored in oldCount, and stores the result 
    //   in newCount
    newCount = oldCount + 1;

    // Makes a string from the number (not strictly necessary) 
    //   and replaces the HTML content of counterDiv with that string
    counterDiv.innerHTML = newCount.toString();

  }
}
```

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  }
```

```html
<div id=clickableDiv>Click me</div>
<div id="counterDiv">0</div>
```